# Mapping C# GIS Types(either using NetTopologySuite or System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography) to PostGIS using Entity Framework edmx file

Tags: entity-framework-6, postgis, npgsql

I'm coding C# application infrastructure trying to use EntityFramework 6 with PostGIS DB.
I use VS 2015 Update 3 with Npgsql 4.0.1.0.
I have installed Npgsql.vsix of the same version.
I've tried to use DataBase first approach but I've the following error inside the edmx file:

```
warning 6005: The data type 'geography' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'geog' in the table 'postgis_24_sample.public.district_municipalities_2016' was excluded.
```

and my created entity had not got the "geography" type property.
So I've added manually "geography" property to my entity using the edmx edit wizard.
I've tried System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography type. It has been added at the edmx:ConceptualModels section of the edmx file but I had no way to map it to DB column.
When I have tried to "Generate Database from Model..." I've got the following error

### Not supported edm type: Edm.Geography

I've tried to change the type to NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry
I have not been able to map it even  in the edmx:ConceptualModels section

What can I do in order to get the support for the GIS types mapping?